# How to compare user input to an array to increase efficency

Tags: arrays, for-loop, python-3.7, dice, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to increase the efficiency of some working code or reduce the number of loops required. Is there a way to use an array or list to validate user input?

So far I've managed to get the code working with a for-else-loop, but it looks cumbersome and not very pythonic. I can't find any answers that involve comparing an array to user input. The code should check if user input matches the right number of sides for valid dice. (So they can't put something like 3 sides)

```py
def check(die):
    if die == 100 or die == 20 or die == 12 or die == 10 or die == 8 or die == 6 or die == 4:
        legal = True
    else:
        legal = False
    return legal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
def check(die,List_Of_Values):
    if die in List_Of_Values:
        legal = True
    else:
        legal = False
    return legal
List_Of_Values=[100,20,12,10,8,6,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert all of those constant values into an array, then loop through that array to check if the values is *legal*

Comment: like iterating with a for loop? Edit: NVm that was a dumb question. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can simplify it even more if you do this:

```py
# Declare as global variable somewhere...
List_Of_Values=[100,20,12,10,8,6,4]


# Sometime later
input = get_input()
if input in List_Of_Values:
  print("Legal")
else:
  print("Not legal")
```

No need for extra function.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the answer!